# embed xtext plugin in notepad++

Tags: java, notepad++, xtext

I developed an Xtext plugin for my DSL but I would like to use it in a lightweight editor like npp. So i have search a bit and I saw that someone has developed a npp plugin in Ada. It means that they manage to wrap the npp features using Ada. But the main difference is that Ada does not need any JVM.

I would like to do the same but with an Xtext plugin. I am interested in the syntactic analysis brought by Xtext.

Does someone succeeded in it?
Does someone have any clue making it regarding the JVM issue or the Xtext features wrapped for npp?

Comment: maybe the more practical way would be to implement the client side of the microsoft language server protocol as plugin for NPP and connect to a xtext based server side

Comment: and what about implementing a npp plugin that would spawn a jvm with xtext inside ?

Comment: that is what the xtext lsp server side already does. if you imlement the client side using the language server protocol then you could run all language servers in npp. maybe there is even already a plugin available